# React setState doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state, setstate

I saw thousands post about it so I am a bit confuse, I did use arrow function, I binded my method changed for componentDidUpdate but I still can't manage to

in my async call setState my data and pass it to my child component.

**ParentComponent**

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNav: 1,
      loading: true,
      data: []
    };
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    var that = this;
    getMyData()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res); // Output res Object
        that.setState({
          data: res
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  componentDidUpdate = () => this.fetchData()

  render() {
    const { data, loading } = this.state;
 return (
      <>

            <ChildComponent data={this.data} loading={loading}/>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
class CurrentUp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidUpdate = () => {
        console.log(this.props.data);   // Output []
        console.log(this.props.loading); // Output true
    }
}
render() {
        console.log(this.props.data);   // Output []
        console.log(this.props.loading); // Output true
        return (
             <div>
             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What am I missing ?

**Solved**, i am not sure how. I kept trying different stuff

Answer (score 0):

You are console logging the data in the `componentDidMount` method. This method runs only once when a component is mounted. When you update the data in the parent component, and pass it to the child component, it doesn't re-create the entire component instance. Only the updates are passed down. You can access those updates in `componentDidUpdate` method. Or, if you are directly accessing props, you can log the data inside the `render` method.

```js
class CurrentUp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render = () => {
        console.log(this.props.data);  
        console.log(this.props.loading);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Other points:

- You don't need to bind the function with `this` if you are using an arrow function.
- Inside the arrow function, it is safe to use the `this` keyword. No need of assigning it to `that`.

Comment: I tried with componentDidUpdate but nothing changed. I as well tried to log in the render() as you show but still the same problem :/
I just edited my post to show you

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring some more code cause I see the child component you posted is an instead current up component. Send the real child component and then move the var in your fetchData function to the constructor.

Comment: That could be a comment